# Mail() with attachment file doesn't work (PHP + HTML)

Tags: php, html, email

I'm trying to send an email with an attachment file but doesn't work, I can't receive any file.

Syntactically it seems to be correct since I don't have any mail anywhere, the problem is that I don't get any mail.

This is my HTML code:

```
 html>
  <head>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="hola.php" method="post">
      <input type="file" name="csv" id="csv" value="RUN"/><br/>
      <input type="submit" value="enviar">
    </form>
  <body>
</html>
```

And this is my PHP code:

```
  $recipient_email = 'prueba@prueba.com';
  $subject = "Mensaje de prueba";
  $message = "Hola, esto es una prueba";

  if (isset($_FILES['csv'])) {
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name'];
    $name = $_FILES['my_file']['name'];
    $size = $_FILES['my_file']['size'];
    $type = $_FILES['my_file']['type'];
    $error = $_FILES['my_file']['error'];

    $total = count($_FILES['csv']['name']);

    for( $i=0 ; $i < $total ; $i++ ) {
      $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'][$i];

      $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
      $headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n";
      $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$reply_to_email."\r\n";
      $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n";
      $headers .= "From:" . "doc@gestio.aliance-brother.com";

      $mensaje .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=".$file_name."\r\n"; 
      $mensaje .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name."\r\n"; 
      $mensaje .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"; 
      $mensaje .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000, 99999)."\r\n\r\n";  
      $mensaje .= $encoded_content;

      mail($recipient_email, $subject, $mensaje, $headers);
      
    }

    header('Location: https://' . $servidor . '/home.php');

}
```

Comment: did you try printing files variable? echo "<pre>"; print_r($_FILES); echo "</pre>"; exit; Do you get anything???

Answer (score 0):

Add **enctype="multipart/form-data"** attribute to the form.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp